# Flutter MVVM Stacked

Tags: flutter, dart, mvvm, stacked

i am new in Flutter and MVVM. I don't understand, how I can trigger methods in my view after a timer ends. I know that I can notifyListeners and use my properties from my ViewModel in my Widget tree. But what if I want to call a method?

View:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gagm_app/splash/splash_page_view_model.dart';
import 'package:stacked/stacked.dart';

class SplashPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashPageState createState() => _SplashPageState();
}

class _SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> {
  SplashPageViewModel _viewModel;

  void methodToTrigger() {
    //doSomething
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ViewModelBuilder.reactive(
        onModelReady: (model) => {_viewModel = model},
        builder: (context, model, child) => Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage(
                        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547665979-bb809517610d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=675&q=80'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover),
              ),
            ),
        viewModelBuilder: () => SplashPageViewModel());
  }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:stacked/stacked.dart';

class SplashPageViewModel extends BaseViewModel {
  bool _hasFinishedTimer = false;
  bool get hasFinshedTimer => _hasFinishedTimer;

  void startTimer() {
    Timer _timer;
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {
      _hasFinishedTimer = true;
      _timer.cancel();

      //view.methodToTrigger()
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Use provider for updating views

Answer (score 1):

Following the MVVM principle, you don't have an logic inside the View, except how the view is displayed. I guess you should move your method into your ViewModel.

But if this method is needed to run some view logic, you better provide some more info.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `StateFullWidget` when using `ViewModel`.
You are using `ViewModel` incorrectly.

```
class ProfileScreen extends StatelessWidget{

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ViewModelBuilder< SplashPageViewModel >.reactive(
     builder: (context, model, child) => Scaffold(),
     viewModelBuilder: () => SplashPageViewModel());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to learn stacked architecture is to read the blogs written by it's creater **Dane**

here are the two articles to get you going [part 1](https://www.filledstacks.com/post/flutter-and-provider-architecture-using-stacked/), [part 2](https://www.filledstacks.com/post/flutter-state-management-with-stacked/), but these articles are almost 2 years old so many things have changed since then, please check the [pub page](https://pub.dev/packages/stacked) of the plugin for any breaking changes.

Answer (score -1):

add your method in the viewmodel and you can call the method from the view.

Comment: Can you give further information to help your answer?